# How to watch changestream in mongoDB and send the updates to an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb, changestream

I'm using the new feature of MongoDB 3.6 **watch()** in order to send updates of the database from the node server to ajax in the client side.

I created a webservice queried periodically by an ajax call. Between two successive ajax calls, i want the second one to get all the updates that occurred in the mean time. I know that i have to resume the change stream as shown in the official documentation here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#resume-a-change-stream . However i didn't find out how to apply this to my specific needs, by that i mean, in which callback can i process my data and send it to the webservice response ?

Here is a part of my **server side code** : server.js

```
const pipeline = [
  {
    $match : {
      "operationType" : "insert"
      ,
      "fullDocument.T" : { "$exists":true}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { "fullDocument.ts": 1,
                "fullDocument.T":1}
  }
];

function getLiveData(handler){

console.log("in getLiveData");
var liveArray=[];

var resumeToken;

const changeStream = dbObject.collection('status').watch(pipeline);
changeStream.hasNext(function(err, change) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  expect(err).to.equal(null);
  expect(change).to.exist;
  console.log("in changeStream.hasNext");

  changeStream.next(function(err, change) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    expect(err).to.equal(null);
    console.log("in changeStream.next");
    resumeToken = change._id;

    expect(change._id).to.exist;
    expect(changeStream.resumeToken).to.exist;

    changeStream.close(function(err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      expect(err).to.equal(null);
      console.log("in changeStream.close");
      const newChangeStream = dbObject.collection('status').watch({ resumeAfter: resumeToken });

      newChangeStream.next(function(err, next) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        expect(err).to.equal(null);
        expect(next).to.exist;
        console.log("in newChangeStream.next");


        //my own code
        newChangeStream.on("change", function(change) {
        console.log('in change stream, change : ',change);
        liveArray.push([change.fullDocument.ts, change.fullDocument.T]);

        var response = {
            "liveArray" : liveArray
        };

        console.log("from getLiveData : " , response);

        handler(response);
      });   
        //my own code

        // Since changeStream has an implicit seession,
        // we need to close the changeStream for unit testing purposes
        newChangeStream.close();
      });
    });
  });
});

}
```

**webservice part :**

```
 app.get("/liveDataRequest", function(req, res){        
      getLiveData(function(data){
        console.log("in handler", data);
        res.status(200).send(data);           
      });
```

And here is the console log, as we can see, the part where i process my data never gets called :

```
in getLiveData
in changeStream.hasNext
in changeStream.next
in changeStream.close
in newChangeStream.next
in getLiveData
in changeStream.hasNext
in changeStream.next
in changeStream.close
in newChangeStream.next
```